# Several different Windows XP desktops recently started randomly going to sleep

Tags: windows-xp, sleep, power-management

Three different HP desktops have been doing this for a few days now.  Nothing has changed.  Two of them are only a few months old while the other is several years old.  All run the latest patches for Windows XP via autoupdate.  Power settings are all set for 'always on', hibernate is disabled, BIOS power settings are either nonexistent or disabled.  I'm baffled.

I recently became aware that the Windows power settings are per-user (which is insane, but let's not go there), so I double-checked while logged in as all the usual users: all good.

These machines do get used for random web surfing by staff here, and while they've been told not to do anything stupid (and we have a fairly sold antivirus solution), I'm worried that something has infected them.  But whoever heard of malware that just randomly makes PCs go to sleep?

Comment: are these users common users or they have admin privileges? check in gpedit.msc for sth about it.

Comment: @kokbira: They are all logged in as the same domain user with no local admin privileges.

Comment: What's the protocol for this situation?  I had a very real problem that solved itself.  There was never an actual 'answer' that I could post here.  I suppose it makes sense to close the question.  I'll wait a while longer to make sure the problem is really gone, then if nobody has any other suggestions, I'll close it.

Comment: @boot13: Perhaps delete it; this isn't going to help anyone in the near future. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few days later, the problem disappeared as suddenly as it started. *Bizarre.*

The problem just disappeared on its own. *Baffling.*

[image]